# Поиск библиотеки для работы с GRIB2 форматом файла

Tags: python, c#, поиск-библиотек, поиск-программ

Задача состоит в том, чтобы забирать необходимые данные из `grib2` формата и преобразовывать в человекочитаемый формат `json`, `xml`. Задача для бэкенда, нужна реализация для python или c#.

Не подходит:

1. Java [реализация](https://github.com/cambecc/grib2json), часть проекта в архиве
2. JavaScript [реализация](https://github.com/f24-it-services/grib2json)

Comment: Что останавливает переписать Java вариант например на C#? Языки очень похожие. Там же не миллион строк кода. И у вас обе ссылки в вопросе одинаковые.

Comment: @aepot надежда, что кто-то уже реализовал=)

Comment: https://github.com/GribApiDotNet/GribApi.NET